# Can a WebView page get location if the hosting iOS app doesn't have location permission?

Tags: ios, uikit, core-location, wkwebview

My iOS app sometimes loads pages in a WebView, and some of these pages (e.g. google.com) ask for user location.

It seems iOS needs my app to have location permission before a webpage (which my app loads) can ask for location permission.

For example, if a user opens google.com in my app's WebView, they're asked to give my app location permission, and then asked to give the current webpage (google.com) location permissions.

(If users have already granted my app location permission, then they only see the location prompt from google.com)

I need a way to avoid prompting users to enable location in my app. I'm not using their location, I just want to avoid breaking location-aware webpages that my users browse to.

This behaviour occurs on iOS 10 and 11. My app is serving webpages in WkWebViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you cannot get the user's location without asking them to grant permission.